# NuxtJS Distributed Static Page Generation

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there a way to split the static page generation process to multiple machines? I'm currently using NuxtJS to statically generate ~150k pages and it takes quite a while to generate those pages (~ 1 hour).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using the [payload key](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload), then I guess that you're at the max possible capabilities of vanilla Nuxt.

Meanwhile, you could split the build into several Nuxt apps and generate several parts side by side aka 3 Nuxt apps building 50k pages each, or use some CI to extract those from your Nuxt app and merge them back.
(basically, homemade code to handle the diff and do not generate stuff already done)

You can check this video: [The Best of Both Worlds: ISG for Nuxt by Ishan Anand](https://youtu.be/G8aq4n9F9E4) that happened on the latest NuxtNation, with an interesting approach.

---

PS: 150k pages in 1 hour looks decent to me! Depending of the pages, maybe some low level optimizations ([functional components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) for example) could be used to win some minutes.

Also, [Nuxt Nitro](https://youtu.be/ApUPE8b-m04) with Nuxt3 may be a good solution to avoid the static generation build time I guess.

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to make the folder filenames inside /_nuxt/static/ to be constant across multiple nuxt builds? For example, whenever I build nuxt apps, there is this /_nuxt/static with a directory inside of it with a random numerical filename (i.e. /_nuxt/static/1636111706/___/payload.js)