# NuxtJS Dist Static folder

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

When I build a NuxtJS app, there is this folder in the dist directory, /_nuxt/static/(some random number)/ (i.e. `/_nuxt/static/1636112212`). This folder contains the `payload.js` and `state.js` for each route that is statically generated. I would like to set a custom folder name for this maybe in the `nuxt.config.js` file. Is there a way / config to do this in NuxtJS?

Comment: `for this`, refering to the `/dist` directory? Also, why do you want this?

Comment: Hi. This is related to this question and to your answer there as well `(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834535/nuxtjs-distributed-static-page-generation?noredirect=1#comment123473193_69834535)`. I'm thinking of merging dist folders from multiple nuxt builds however for each nuxt build, a randomly generated number is used for the folder name inside /_nuxt/static. I was just wondering if there is an existing config in nuxt that allows to set that folder name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be undocumented, but the random number that is used for the static directory is actually a version which is calculated every time (probably for cache breaking).

You can make it the same every time you generate by setting it in your nuxt.config.js:

```
  generate: {
    staticAssets: {
      version: "1",
    },
  }
```

In this case I used "1", but I assume that can be any valid path string.  With a value here, the number won't change from build to build.